# Sql split the column which has comma in SQL SERVER 2019

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, csv, sql-server-2019

Hi I am looking for HELP in splitting the column which has Comma in sql

[image]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The type of database matters here, but you didn't list one. There are many solutions posted out there (search for how to strip an email address in sql).

Here's how I would do it in postgres...

```
    select 
    c1, 
    split_part(c1, ',', 1) AS c2,
    split_part(c1, ',', 2) AS c3
    from table_name
```

Comment: I am using SQL SERVER 2019

Comment: @BARG so tag your question properly so that people don't waste their time giving you solution to the wrong dbms!!!

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2019 provides a built-in string splitter, called `string_split()`, that can turn a CSV string to rows. Alas, it cannot keep track of the original position of each element in the CSV string, which makes it unsuitable for a task such as yours.

We can, however, use the `openjson()` trick: the idea is to slightly manipulate the string to make it a valid JSON array, that we can then unnest (with ordinality!).

Consider:

```
select t.*, x.*
mytable t
cross apply (
    select 
        max(case when key = 1 then value end) col1,
        max(case when key = 2 then value end) col2,
        max(case when key = 3 then value end) col3,
        ...
    from openjson('["' +  replace(@str,',','","') + '"]')
) x;
```

Of course, this requires that you know in advance the maximum number of columns that you want in the resultset. You can expand the `select` clause of the subquery with additional conditional expressions to generate more columns.